# CSS left, right div background issue

Tags: css, background-image

I have two divs. One for left menu and one for the content on right side. The left menu have a background image, but it doesnt stretch 100 % of the site.

```css
#main_wrapper{

}
#main_left{
    float: left;
    background: #fbfcff url("gfx/main_left_bg.jpg") repeat-y top right;
    width: 210px;
}
#main_right{
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_wrapper">
  <div id="main_left"></div>
  <div id="main_right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean? If the background should stretch across the whole site, you have to assign it to `body`, not to any DIV

Comment: Why would it stretch 100% if you put the width to a fixed 210px value?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the height of your main wrapper to 100vh if you want its children to stretch the entire height of the window.

```css
#main_wrapper {
  height: 100vh;;
  width: 100vw;
}

#main_left {
  float: left;
  width: 210px;
  
  background-image: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/518079-background-hd.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  height: 100%;
}
#main_right {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_wrapper">
  <div id="main_left"></div>
  <div id="main_right"></div>
</div>
```